# Tool for Azure functions log visualiser ( similar to Service Trace Viewer Tool for WCF)

Tags: azure, wcf, azure-functions

Is/Are there tools for tracing and visualisation of Azure Function similar to  [Service Trace Viewer Tool for WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/service-trace-viewer-tool-svctraceviewer-exe) ?

With the Azure PaaS paradigm , are there any visualisation tools available for tracing and/or dependency of Azure functions on each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to collect the logs or error data to monitor Function.

Actually Azure Function has built-in integration with Azure Application Insights to monitor Function. Further more information you could refer to this doc:[Monitor Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring).

What you need is create a Application Insights resource and go to the Function Settings enable Application Insights. In there you could create a new Application Insights or choose the one you have created.

[image]

[image]

Then you will be able to view Function data in the Azure Application Insights. Hope this could help you.

Comment: Azure Application Insights! Thank you for mentioning that.